# Include 3rd jar to eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Firstly, I have tried the method given in official page of [eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_FAQ#I.27m_using_third_party_jar_files_and_my_plug-in_is_not_working) . But I really do not get my gson jar working, the error is still : Class not found.

This is my manifest.fm :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Eclipseplugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.snipplr.eclipseplugin; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.snipplr.eclipseplugin.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: SNIPPLR
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.7.1",
 org.eclipse.ui.editors;bundle-version="3.7.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: com.google.gson
Bundle-ClassPath: library.jar,
 .
Import-Package: com.google.gson
```

I just declare a simple gson as : `Gson gson = new Gson();`

**My question is:**

What's wrong in my doing ?

After the success following Francis answer, I have another question. Can I simplify the steps to how to include 3rd jar :

1. Step 1 : add jar file to your project
2. Step 2 : Bundle-ClassPath: library.jar, .  << Add bundle-classpath which lead to your jar to manifest.fm

Does it work ?

If you need any information, just ask in comment. I will watch this all day till it's done :P . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Bundle-Classpath needs to have gson.jar in it. You can do this in the manifest file directly, or on the Runtime tab add it to the classpath part with the GUI.

To answer your further questions:

Well step 2 would be to include your gson.jar file. I don't know what's in library.jar. As I said above you can do that through the GUI by using the classpath portion of the Runtime tab in the manifest editor. Adding it to the classpath there will also add it to your Java build classpath.

You also don't need to have the Export-Package for com.google.json if you are just using it in your plugin, the purpose of Export-Package is to provide it to another plugin that might use your plugin.

Comment: I remember I did this yesterday but it messed up. Now I just add my gson.jar to manifest as : lib/json-2.0.jar and it works. Thanks for helping me :D ah, one more question I add above.

Comment: absolutely, however, can you answer my edited question by editing your answer. I will be very happy if you do that ;)

Comment: thanks for your help, if I can I will give you double accept :P